# How to handle list of string stored in a map in python?

Tags: python

I am from C++ background and i am porting one of our tool to python, i am fairly a begginer with python and i am looking for way to store this data structure to python

i have a map or array with string key and it will have a content of an object or a json like so..

```
map["key1"] = {
     { 'name': 'user1', 'email': 'something@something'},
     { 'name': 'user1', 'email': 'something@something'},
     ...
}

map["key2"] = {
     { 'name': 'user1', 'email': 'something@something'},
     { 'name': 'user1', 'email': 'something@something'},
     ...
}
...
```

ofcourse the map list should be growing whenevern there is a new key.

how to do this in python?

Comment: You are looking for [dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use a Python dictionary which is denoted by squiggly brackets (`{` and `}`). The data structure inside the dictionary entry is a list denoted by the square brackets (`[` and `]`).

```py
# Declare 'my_map' dictionary
my_map = {}

# Add list of dictionaries to 'key_1'
my_map["key1"] = [
     { 'name': 'user1', 'email': 'something@something'},
     { 'name': 'user1', 'email': 'something@something'}
]

# Add list of dictionaries to 'key_2'
my_map["key2"] = [
     { 'name': 'user1', 'email': 'something@something'},
     { 'name': 'user1', 'email': 'something@something'}
]
```